# Android make preview from images on web

Tags: android

I'm trying to make preview as Thumbnail from images on web before downloading, it means i have more item on `RecyclerView` and i'm trying to view simple blurred preview from images but i dont know whats solution, i use this below code but i think this code download full image, like with social application such as whatsApp or Telegram how can i make preview image on web and show that to users?

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //First create a new URL object
        URL url = null;
        try {
            if (checkNetWorkConnection()) {
                url = new URL("http://wallpaperwarrior.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Wallpaper-2.jpeg");

                //Next create a file, the example below will save to the SDCARD using JPEG format

                File file = new File(APP.DIR_APP + APP.IMAGE + "/" + "Wallpaper-2.jpg");
                //Next create a Bitmap object and download the image to bitmap
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openStream());

                //Finally compress the bitmap, saving to the file previously created
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, new FileOutputStream(file));
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Error ", e.getMessage());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Error ", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Error ", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try implement with this [zoom effect](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html). It is being use by many application. With the example you can create your own background like full screen black background but you need to implement it yourself which is pretty simple but kinda lot of work to do.

Beside why not try to use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) to download and display the image? It help you save a lot work such as caching, download in asyncs,resize etc.

When you work with image especially with recycleview or listview there is some problem you need to always remember. Every time you scroll the listView/RecycleView it actually re-download the image so you have to really check wether it already exist in your sdcard to avoid this problem beside there is better to cache is memory although you already save it on sd card but still you can avoid memory crash by cache it in memory. Those hard work done by using either one of the library I just show you.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use picasso lib.

```
Picasso  
.with(context)
.load("http://wallpaperwarrior.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Wallpaper-2.jpeg")
.resize(600, 200)
.centerInside() 
.into(imageViewResizeCenterInside);
```

> You can give circle shape to image using Transformation api of picasso.
>   refer this [Picasso](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit)